# How to keep order of columns consistent after aggregation functions in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create an aggregated dataframe of many sensor readings over time to just the sums for each sensor.  I have many dataframes but they all have the same schema, with 10 columns, one for each sensor:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+ 
|sensor_1|sensor_2|sensor_3|sensor_4|sensor_5|sensor_6|sensor_7|sensor_8|sensor_9|sensor_10|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+ 
|   220.0|   339.0|  -336.0|   364.0|    null|   492.0|  -796.0|  -423.0|  -582.0|    -40.0| 
|   178.0|   221.0|  -317.0|   366.0|    null|   525.0|  -754.0|  -415.0|  -932.0|   -305.0| 
|   151.0|    42.0|  -280.0|   250.0|    null|   463.0|  -772.0|  -229.0|  -257.0|    -59.0| 
|   162.0|  -123.0|  -243.0|   288.0|    null|   303.0|  -899.0|   212.0|  -295.0|     38.0| 
|   158.0|  -287.0|  -300.0|   372.0|    null|   169.0|  -769.0|   755.0|   169.0|   -239.0| 
|   136.0|  -302.0|  -308.0|   242.0|    null|   241.0|  -510.0|   888.0|   282.0|   -293.0| 
|   124.0|  -131.0|  -292.0|   132.0|    null|   234.0|  -494.0|   970.0|  -326.0|   -203.0| 
|   127.0|   133.0|  -208.0|    14.0|    null|   134.0|  -748.0|   700.0|   237.0|   -278.0| 
|   142.0|   374.0|   -81.0|  -177.0|    null|  -200.0|  -678.0|   402.0|   664.0|   -460.0| 
|   135.0|   538.0|    52.0|  -113.0|    null|  -440.0|  -711.0|    35.0|   877.0|   -452.0|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Can try recreating a small version of the dataframe with

```
columns = ['sensor_1','sensor_2','sensor_3','sensor_4','sensor_5','sensor_6','sensor_7','sensor_8','sensor_9','sensor_10']
data = [(220.0,   339.0,  -336.0,   364.0,    null,   492.0,  -796.0,  -423.0,  -582.0,    -40.0),
       (178.0,   221.0,  -317.0,   366.0,    null,   525.0,  -754.0,  -415.0,  -932.0,   -305.0),
       (151.0,    42.0,  -280.0,   250.0,    null,   463.0,  -772.0,  -229.0,  -257.0,    -59.0)]

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Sensors').getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df = rdd.toDF()
```

AFter I try to create the sums DataFrame with:

```
exprs = {x: "sum" for x in df.columns}
sum_df = df.agg(exprs)
```

This gives the following output.

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+ 
|sum(sensor_2)|sum(sensor_9)|sum(sensor_3)|sum(sensor_8)|sum(sensor_4)|sum(sensor_7)|sum(sensor_1)|
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|     276834.0|      87904.0|     213587.0|      76103.0|     121201.0|     423609.0|     -96621.0|         
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

As you can see the columns are out of order to the original. I had to trim the display of the whole df to fit neatly in this post but you get the idea.  I'm not sure what logical ordering the spark engine decided to use but it doesn't suit me because I need them to have consistent order.  Why does it do this? how can I keep the order consistent?

Comment: I think since you are using *dict* to create the expr, it is causing this reordering. you can use *OrderedDict* from *collections* to resolve this.

Comment: You can you use with a Pyspak DF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets try using list comprehension;

```
df1=df.agg(*[f.sum(x).alias(x) for x in df.columns])
df1.show()
```

Comment: This gives me the error - `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sum'`

Comment: Which is which, you seem to have accepted the answer. Anyway, agg can be applied to a df. Without having details of what your real dataframe looks like I can tell the cause of error. I have applied this to a 2m row df and it worked.

Comment: I accepted it before I got this error.  Can you explain what "f" is?

Comment: `import pyspark.sql.functions as f`

Comment: Thanks that cleared it up.  Was also wondering how to get the alias column name like sum(sensor_1).